Evaluate metric over all batches in tensorflow
I have written a metric for tensorflow which is the area under the Precision-Recall curve to the left of the recall=0.3 threshold. The implementation is (notice I only care about the zeroth prediction of the last timestep in which window):
   def auprc_left_of_recall(y_true, y_pred, recall_threshold=0.3):

    y_true = y_true[:, -1, 0]
    y_pred = y_pred[:, -1, 0]

    recall_threshold = tf.constant(recall_threshold)

    indices = tf.argsort(y_pred, direction='DESCENDING')
    sorted_y_true = tf.gather(y_true, indices)

    cum_true_positives = K.cumsum(sorted_y_true)
    cum_false_positives = K.cumsum(1 - sorted_y_true)
    total_positives = K.sum(sorted_y_true)

    precision = cum_true_positives / (cum_true_positives + cum_false_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = cum_true_positives / (total_positives + K.epsilon())

    before_mask = recall < recall_threshold
    after_mask = recall >= recall_threshold

    idx_before = tf.reduce_max(tf.where(before_mask))
    idx_after = tf.reduce_min(tf.where(after_mask))

    recall_before = recall[idx_before]
    recall_after = recall[idx_after]
    precision_before = precision[idx_before]
    precision_after = precision[idx_after]

    interpolated_precision = precision_before + (precision_after - precision_before) * (recall_threshold - recall_before) / (recall_after
     - recall_before)

    precision_left = tf.concat([tf.boolean_mask(precision, before_mask), [interpolated_precision]], axis=0)
    recall_left = tf.concat([tf.boolean_mask(recall, before_mask), [recall_threshold]], axis=0)

    precision_left = tf.concat([[1.0], precision_left], axis=0)
    recall_left = tf.concat([[0.0], recall_left], axis=0)

    recall_diff = recall_left[1:] - recall_left[:-1]
    avg_precision = (precision_left[1:] + precision_left[:-1]) / 2
    area = tf.reduce_sum(recall_diff * avg_precision)

    return area

However, when aggregated over batches through the mean over batches, the result obviously does not correspond to what I would expect (it works perfectly if there is a single validation/test batch).
How would I implement a metric which evaluates exactly what the metric above does, but over the labels and predictions of all batches at once?
